# The are any CMYK graphics library?

Tags: tiff, jpeg, cmyk

I'm looking for graphics library with CMYK support(JPG or TIF). I have to read one big image file and one small, then write second on first. Output have to be also CMYK(without any CMYK->RGB conversion). There are any? (C#/C++/Java or somthing else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer, I work for Atalasoft)
[Atalasoft dotImage](http://www.atalasoft.com) will read and write images in as CMYK as well as perform overlay operations in CMYK space.

the code you would need to do this is:

```
public void OverlayCMYKOnCMYK(Stream bottomStm, Stream topStm, Point location, Steam outStm)
{
    using (AtalaImage bottom = new AtalaImage(bottomStm, null), top = new AtalaImage(topStm, null)) {
        // might want to check that both bottom and top have the same PixelFormat
        // OverlayCommand will silently do conversions if they don't match.            
        OverlayCommand overlay = new OverlayCommand(top, location);
        overlay.Apply(bottom);
        bottom.Save(outStm, new TiffEncoder(), null);
   }
}
```

Comment: is there any library for making the color of fonts CMYK with out conversion from RGB to CMYK?